# Property from UITextInputTraits can't be assigned

Tags: swift, uitextview, protocols, uitextinputtraits

I encounter strange compile error when accessing UITextView as object conforming to UITextInputTraits:

```
protocol MyEditingView:UITextInputTraits where Self: UIView {
}

extension UITextView:MyEditingView {
}

class SomeClass {
  var editingView:MyEditingView = UITextView()
  func someFunc() {
    editingView.autocorrectionType = .no
  }
}
```

**"Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable"**

But if property is explicitly declared in protocol, without 
inheriting from UITextInputTraits it is compiled successfully.

```
protocol MyEditingView where Self: UIView {
  var autocorrectionType: UITextAutocorrectionType { get set }
}
```

And property declaration is same as in UITextInputTraits.

Swift 4.2, XCode 10.1

Comment: Are you aware that `UITextView` already conforms to `UITextInputTraits`? There is no need for your protocol or extension.

Comment: @maddy, yes, but as you can see, we speak about different protocol which in real code contains more properties. They are simply not included here because they are  not related to question.

Answer (score 1):

autocorrectionType property is **optional** inside UITextInputTraits but when you declare it explicitly in **MyEditingView** its no more optional property. 
I tried making it optional property in MyEditingView and got the same compilation error.

Comment: Thank you @Subash thapa, yes it optional that cause an error. But it is still not clear why this irrelevant error is shown.